# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query()/prepare() on null. No PDO function works. it always says Call to a member function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**This is my Class Code**

```
<?php 

class DatabaseFunctions{

    public $serverName  = SERVER_NAME ;
    public $userName    = USER_NAME ;
    public $password    = PASSWORD ;
    public $dbName      = DB_NAME ;

    public $pdo;
    public $error;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_connect();        
    }

    private function db_connect()
    {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->serverName;dbname=$this->dbName", 
                   $this->userName, $this->password);    
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
            //echo 'Connected successfully'; 
            }

        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function userIndex($query)
    {       
        //$stmt = $this->pdo->query($query);
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt-> rowCount() > 0)
        {
            return $read;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**And This is my **

```
    <?php
    session_start();    
    include('../../class/config.php');
    include('../../class/DatabaseFunctions.php');
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

    $db=new DatabaseFunctions();
    $query='SELECT * FROM members';
    $read=$db->userIndex($query);   
    print_r($read); 
    ?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   in
>   D:\Laravel\Xamp_new\htdocs\mou\bikroy\bikroyplus\class\DatabaseFunctions.php:33
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\Laravel\Xamp_new\htdocs\mou\bikroy\bikroyplus\admin\pages\users.php(12):
>   DatabaseFunctions->userIndex('SELECT * FROM m...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   D:\Laravel\Xamp_new\htdocs\mou\bikroy\bikroyplus\class\DatabaseFunctions.php
>   on line 33

it's the error.. Please help me..
Note: Database successfully connected. but no pdo function works. it says Call to a member function. Please help me.

Comment: You should also probably change the server connection vars from `public` declarations to `private`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your connect function, `$pdo` is only defined inside the function, you need to assign it to `$this->pdo`...

```
function db_connect() { 
    try { 
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->serverName;dbname=$this->dbName", 
            $this->userName, $this->password); 
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

        //echo 'Connected successfully'; 
    } catch(PDOException $e) { 
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works.. Some time my brain hangs like pc and does't work. Thank you so much

Comment: if it works for you, upvote, so that it helps others